# Why $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_2^x \frac{\sin^2{t}}{t}\, dt\geq \lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{2\pi}^x \frac{\sin^2{t}}{t}\, dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Why can I say that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_2^x \frac{\sin^2{t}}{t}\, dt\geq \lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{2\pi}^x \frac{\sin^2{t}}{t}\, dt$?

I have thought that it is due by the fact that passing from $2$ to $2\pi$ I am restricting the interval of integration but I am not sure. 
Or it is due simply by the fact that $\int_2^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2{t}}{t}\, dt\geq 0$ and it is the missing term in the right hand side? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\sin^2t/t \ge 0$ for all $t > 0$, you have $$\int_2^x \frac{\sin^2t}{t}dt \ge \int_{2\pi}^x \frac{\sin^2t}{t}dt$$
The inequality does not change while limiting both sides.

The above inequality is easy to observe since
$$\int_2^x \text{positive} ~dt = \underbrace{\int_2^{2\pi} \text{positive} ~dt}_{\ge 0} + \int_{2\pi}^x \text{positive} ~dt \ge \int_{2\pi}^x \text{positive} ~dt$$

Comment: Ok thank you very much!!

Comment: I can accept you answer by $5$ min as a message tells me! I will do it!

Comment: @cely No hurry, that's fine. Glad that it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\sin^2(t)\ge 0$ due to it being a squared function. $\frac1t>0$ is also due to our domain. This means that our integrand over our domain is always greater than or equal to zero. Now we can just split our integral up:
$$\int_2^xf(t)dt=\underbrace{\int_2^{2\pi}f(t)dt}_{\ge 0}+\int_{2\pi}^xf(t)dt$$
Now as we can see this will then create our inequality since LHS and RHS are just your integrals in question